# How to pass use_legacy_sql=False to the SqlSensor in an Airflow DAG with a BigQuery connection?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am using my own custom SqlSensor since the release of Apache Airflow 1.9, as I was unable to use the one included with Standard SQL statements operating on Google BigQuery, because the default is to [use legacy SQL](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/cec54947d7cf0489284995a6a899b9b94620e301/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L57).

I've checked the recent 1.10.3 release and it seems this is still the case. Is there any other way to make this work besides using my own SQL sensor as a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The quickest solution I found was

- Define a new class BigQuerySqlSensor
- Override the `_get_hook` method
- Set `use_legacy_sql=False` in override
- Return the updated hook

```py
from airflow.sensors.sql_sensor import SqlSensor

class BigQuerySqlSensor(SqlSensor):
    def _get_hook(self):
        hook = super()._get_hook()
        hook.use_legacy_sql = False
        return hook

sense_stuff = BigQuerySqlSensor(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='sense_stuff',
        conn_id='the_connection_id',
        sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table",
        mode='reschedule',
        poke_interval=600,
        timeout=(3600)
    )
```

Comment: This is what I meant with "I am using my own custom SqlSensor" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Update your Custom Sensor to pass `use_legacy_sql=False` to the BigQueryHook.

```
hook = BigQueryHook(
            bigquery_conn_id=self.bigquery_conn_id,
            delegate_to=self.delegate_to,
            use_legacy_sql=False
       )
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am currently doing, but I was wondering if there is a way of doing it without a plugin.

Comment: You don't need to do it with plugin. You already have you Custom Sensor, right? You can add this code to that sensor.

Comment: The Custom Sensor is a plugin, it's code that I have to maintain and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [enabling standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) topic in the documentation, if you can't set the option directly, another approach is to use the `#standardSQL` shebang, e.g.:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT x
FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3]) AS x;
```

It should be possible to submit queries using this prefix to override the setting.

Comment: This does not work as it's sending contradicting settings towards the API:
```"Query text specifies use_legacy_sql:false, while API options specify:true"```